# TinyMCE: Rename Image File Name Before Upload

Tags: tinymce

I've been struggling with this.

I've got tinyMCE set up so that users can upload images, I have `images_reuse_filename` set to true, I have a custom `images_upload_handler`, and I have `images_reuse_filename` set to true.

In my custom upload handler, I `console.dir` the `blobInfo` (the upload handler has the signature `(blobInfo, success, failure)`, which I think I got from the docs)

The problem is `blobInfo.filename` is a function with no way that I can see to set the filename.[image]

I'm using tinyMCE for users to be able to create email templates, and I'm figuring they'll want to use some images such as logos, headers, across many templates.

When the page loads, I populate the `image_list` with their existing images.

The problem of course is `blobid1587911717487.png` is meaningless to the user. And I don't want to waste my database space with an extraneous table to store a `title` for tinyMCE.

What I want to do is capture the original filename, check it against a `validFilenameChars` function, then present the filename to the user in case s/he wants to alter it, then pass that along further down the train in the `images_upload_handler`.

Oh, and I need to handle when a user resizes the image.

I would include code, but it's a pain in the ass to strip code of non-relevant code to present the core of the issue, and, if you're intimately familiar with tinyMCE, I'll reckon you know what I'm talking about and don't need my code.

If you think/know you can figure it out and want the code, lemme know.

I've spent an inordinate amount of time trying to figure this out, any help will be appreciated.

I'm using `Version: 5.2.1` of tinyMCE

Also, tinyMCE is a pretty powerful ***free*** html editor, I feel like I'm looking a gift-horse in the mouth by saying this, but wtf over? How did they miss that a user would upload images that would then be included in their `image_list` and maybe want sensible names? Is it just me? Maybe. TinyMCE is largely a black box to me, so dunno their internal decisions. So... if you know of another html editor that can be used in lieu of tinyMCE that is open-source, lemme know.

Also, great job on the new docs tinyMCE! Love 'em.

Comment: Michael - we do offer a solution to your entire problem called MoxieManager but it is not a free or open source product.  The issue you describe is not a simple one to address as you have noticed.

Comment: Michael - not suggesting you should buy anything.  The issue of image management is a large one and not as simple as image upload.  If MoxieManager does not suit your needs there are certainly other options out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a hack-around that requires 2 posts to the server, one that uploads the image and then after that, another that will rename the file on the server. Then I pass the new location on to the `success` function. My code's a little hacky too, but I was just after proof of concept.

```
function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    var self = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', self.imagesUploadUrl);

    xhr.onload = function () {

        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        // I have a DTO on the server that separates out the filename
            from the path and file extension
        var filename = prompt('If you plan on reusing this image in other templates, rename the file so that it\'s easily recognizable in your images list', json.filename);

        if (filename && filename !== json.filename) {
            json.filename = filename;

            axios.post(self.imageRenameUrl, json)
                .then(function (r) {
                    var renamedImage = r.data;
                    success(renamedImage.location);
                })
        }
        else {
            success(filename);
        }
    };

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It prevents a new copy from being created when the uploaded file is edited with "images Tools". It is created only when you upload a new file.

Make the following setting.

```
tinymce.init({
            paste_data_images: false,
            images_reuse_filename: true,
            automatic_uploads: true,
            images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
                                
                var  formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
                
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:  'ajax.upload.php',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache:false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(r){
                        if (r.error) {
                            alert("r.error");
                        } else if (r.message) {
                            success(r.message.location);
                        }                        
                    },
                    complete: function (jqXHR,exception) {
                       $('.tox-dialog__busy-spinner').hide();
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR,exception) {
                        
                    }
                });
                
            }  
  });
```

### PHP CODE:

```
 // Yüklenecek dosya adı, yüklenen dosyaların adlarında var ise mevcut ad kullanılır.
    if( $_SESSION['TEMP_UPLOADED_IMAGES'][$handle_normal->file_src_name] === true ){
        
        // Dosya zaten mevcut ise otomatik olarak yeniden adlandırmayı devre dışı bırakır. Bu durumda mevcut dosya isimleri var ise üzerine yazılır.
        $handle_normal->file_overwrite = true;
        
             
        
        // Yüklenecek dosyanın adı mevcut adıyla kullanılır. Yeni adlandırma yapılmaz.
        $random_file_name = $handle_normal->file_src_name_body;
    } else {
        // Yüklenecek dosya rastgele adlandırılır.
        $random_file_name = $vd->randomNumbers(10));
    }
```

**This code will run on every file upload. (after upload)**

```
$_SESSION['TEMP_UPLOADED_IMAGES'][$handle_normal->file_dst_name] = true;
```

Comment: The `blobInfo.filename()` still emits something like `blobid0.jpg` instead of the original filename I had. Does this actually work for somebody? I tried TinyMCE version 6.2.